# Setting mouse coordinates on fireEvent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to emulate a `mousemove` event in a link in IE8, but I'm not sure if it's possible to set the coordinates of the mouse in the event. This is my code so far:

```
function Handler()
{
    var dump = "";

    for(var i in event)
    {
        dump += ("" + i) + " => " + event[i] + "\n";
    }

    dumper.value = "";
    dumper.value = dump;
}

function Init()
{
    document.getElementById("link2").attachEvent("onmousemove", function(){Handler();});
}

function Emulate()
{
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    evt.x = 10;
    evt.y = 10;
    document.getElementById("link2").fireEvent("onmousemove", evt);
}
```

The event is being attached by calling the `Init()` function `onload`. When I call `Emulate()` the coordinates are the actual coordinates of the cursor. Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just edited my question to reflect my original failing code (the one I posted was messed up). The solution was to set `clientX` and `clientY` instead. `x` and `y` will automatically get the values assigned to them:

```
function Emulate()
{
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    evt.clientX = 10;
    evt.clientY = 10;
    document.getElementById("link2").fireEvent("onmousemove", evt);
}
```